# What is common way to log exception if message is not a concern

Tags: android

I was wondering, what is the common way to log exception, if message is not my concern.

```
// exp is Exception.
Log.e(TAG, "", exp);
```

or

```
// exp is Exception.
Log.e(TAG, null, exp);
```

Comment: The message may not be your explicit concern, but some contextual information is almost *always* a good idea. Put a message in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Log.getStackTraceString` if you want to avoid the extra message line in your log:

```
Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(exp));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really write a message that is contextual and would make the log message explicit.

Something like:

```
 Log.e(TAG, "Null Pointer when parsing my internet response. Is the web service down?", exp);
```

but if you really don't want to worry about it, you could wrap the Log class with your own class

```
public class MyLog {
     private static final String TAG = "MyApp";

     public static void e(Exception e){
          Log.e(TAG, "", e);
     }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
MyLog.e(exp);
```

Comment: Sorry. But the question is, is `Log.e(TAG, "", e);` or `Log.e(TAG, null, e);` are more commonly used?

Comment: **Neither** are commonly used. You should always write a contextual message. Having a stack trace doesn't always explain why you got that exception.

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK I agree with Blundell; neither is common, and neither is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you *insist* on going against best practices, at *least* use the exception message:

```
Log.e(TAG, exp.getMessage(), exp);
```

To do anything less is irresponsible.